# how to convert an 'integer' string to an 'hex' string C

Tags: c

I have in an integer value as string, `tab[10]="10"` and i want to convert it to an hex value `h=A` add it another value `0x6000` and store it as a string in another array `tab2[50]="600A"` in C

Comment: Cool story. So, where are you stuck?

Comment: try this: `sprintf(tab2,"%x",atoi(tab)+0x6000);`

Comment: Please give us more information. It's quite unclear what exactly you want.

Comment: Can you please post the code as suggested?

Answer (score 1):

You can add integers together regardless of the base because they are all stored as binary values anyway.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){

    char tab[] = "10";
    int num = atoi(tab);
    int num2 = 0x6000;
    int sum = num + num2;
    char tab2[20];

    sprintf(tab2, "%04X", sum);
    puts(tab2);
}
```